# How to stop growing the Apache access_log file?

Tags: apache-2.2, aix

While setting up the Apache HTTP server in AIX, I never realize there is a log file, `access_log`, located at /var/log/httpd. This file is keep growing until 600+ MB, I am not able to keep track of its growing and may bring other issues in the future, may I know can I stop growing the file?

Comment: Shut down the web server. Then the log will stop growing.

Comment: I can't stop the server as I am still using it. How could I write an auto clean script on the file so that I could maintain the file size?

Answer (score 2):

Use something like [logrotate](https://fedorahosted.org/logrotate/), or the [rotatelogs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/rotatelogs.html) utility that came with Apache, to rotate your log files on a regular basis.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about AIX but on other platforms the common way to handle that issue is to rotate the logs.

logrotate and it's configuration at /etc/logrotate.conf is the most common way to do that.

It looks like that is supported on AIX:
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=isg3T1012796

Answer (score 0):

Check the file httpd.conf (or apache2.conf), find the logging related entries and disable them.